# How to use Rybka 2.3.2a for the chess logic in a java program?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program to play chess and I would like to use the Rybka engine for the logic.  There are multiple gui's for the program.  However, I have not found out how they interface with it.
Any help would be appreciated 
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rybka),  [Official Site](http://www.rybkachess.com/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rybka supports [UCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface).  See [here](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks promising.